# Sort key-value pairs descending based on property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I built a K/V pair array based on some values.

**Here is the data structure:**

```
var selItemsDimArray = []

selItemsDimArray.push({
    'examinedElem': multiselected[i],
    'x': bb.x,
    'y': bb.y,
    'x2': (bb.x + bb.width),
    'y2': (bb.y + bb.height),
    'height': bb.height,
    'width': bb.width
});
```

> How can I sort selItemsDimArray numerically(lowest to highest) based
>   on element.x property?

The 'much-loved' W3schools gives me an example of:

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b}); //Where did a and b come from?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
selItemsDimArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    // here a and b are two items from selItemsDimArray array
    // which means it is possible access and compare the x property for both items
    return a.x - b.x;
});
```

[**Array.prototype.sort on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: thanks, but still, where did a and b come from? Where are they defined?

Comment: `a` and `b` are items from the array on which `.sort` is called. JavaScript engine passes two items from that array at a time; _you_ are required to return a number indicating which one is bigger of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Solution
selItemsDimArray.sort(function(a, b){return a.x-b.x});